# How to use include in smarty3 template engine

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7, smarty3

This is my first template for Prestashop 1.7. I use Starter theme. But now I have problem because I want to create new block.

addresses.tpl

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}


{block name='page_content_container'}
<div class="container">
  <div class="account">
  <h2 class="heading">
        {block name='page_title'}
          {l s='Your addresses' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}
        {/block}
      </h2>

    <div class="box">
      <section id="content" class="page-content page-addresses">

        {foreach $customer.addresses as $address}
          {block name='customer_address'}
            {include file='customer/_partials/block-address.tpl' address=$address}
          {/block}
        {/foreach}

        <footer>
          <a href="{$urls.pages.address}" data-link-action="add-address">
            {l s='Create new address' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
          </a>
        </footer>

      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{/block}
```

and page.tpl

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}


{block name='my_account_links'}
  {include file='customer/_partials/my-account-links.tpl'}
{/block}
```

This file extend another page.tpl but there is no my_account_links block. the question is. Why I dont see my_account_links block in addresses.tpl. When I display the page.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your  my_account_links block in addresses.tpl because you don't have any `{block name='my_account_links'}` in addresses.tpl.

If you want to display your page.tpl in your addresses.tpl, you have to "call" the block in your parent file and extends it in your child file ( page.tpl ). Like this :

Addresses.tpl

```
{block name='my_account_links'} <!-- YOUR my_account_links OF YOUR PAGE.TPL WILL BE HERE {/block}
{block name='page_content_container'}
<div class="container">
  <div class="account">
  <h2 class="heading">
        {block name='page_title'}
          {l s='Your addresses' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}
        {/block}
      </h2>

    <div class="box">
      <section id="content" class="page-content page-addresses">

        {foreach $customer.addresses as $address}
          {block name='customer_address'}
            {include file='customer/_partials/block-address.tpl' address=$address}
          {/block}
        {/foreach}

        <footer>
          <a href="{$urls.pages.address}" data-link-action="add-address">
            {l s='Create new address' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
          </a>
        </footer>

      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{/block}
```

And in your page.tpl :

```
{extends file='addresses.tpl'}


{block name='my_account_links'}
  {include file='customer/_partials/my-account-links.tpl'}
{/block}
```

Now, with this, your page.tpl ( the block 'my_account_links' ) will be display in your addresses.tpl

Comment: Uncaught  --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:addresses.tpl' in 'customer/page.tpl' when I add {extends file='addresses.tpl'} in page.tpl

Comment: Put the good path maybe. It's note that your file doesn't exist